# Library insertion/injection not work with open command

Tags: c, macos, macos-carbon, inject, interposing

I writed a dynamic library that loaded into target application by environment variable DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, the dylib works fine when application executed from terminal by this commands:

```
$ export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/path/to/mylib.dylib
$ /path/to/application.app/Contents/MacOS/executable
```

but when execute it by open command:

```
$ open /path/to/application.app
```

this error occured:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library:
```

what is difference between two method of execution?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this issue was that my dylib is 32bit and it first load into "open" which is 64bit.